# Vagrant provisioning failing with closed stream (IOError)

Tags: chef-infra, puppet, vagrant

On Mac OS X when trying to follow the Vagrant tutorial for provisioning with chef, I get the following error. If I use puppet instead, the same issue occurs and if I use lucid32 the same issue occurs. Help?

```
[default] Importing base box 'lucid64'...
[default] The guest additions on this VM do not match the install version of
VirtualBox! This may cause things such as forwarded ports, shared
folders, and more to not work properly. If any of those things fail on
this machine, please update the guest additions and repackage the
box.

Guest Additions Version: 4.1.16
VirtualBox Version: 4.1.18
[default] Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[default] Forwarding ports...
[default] -- 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
[default] Creating shared folders metadata...
[default] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
[default] Booting VM...
[default] Waiting for VM to boot. This can take a few minutes.
[default] VM booted and ready for use!
[default] Mounting shared folders...
[default] -- v-root: /vagrant
[default] Running provisioner: Vagrant::Provisioners::ChefSolo...
[default] Generating chef JSON and uploading...
[default] Running chef-solo...
stdin: is not a tty
[Mon, 30 Jul 2012 08:55:18 +0200] INFO: *** Chef 0.10.10 ***
[Mon, 30 Jul 2012 08:55:18 +0200] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[vagrant_main]"] from JSON
[Mon, 30 Jul 2012 08:55:18 +0200] INFO: Run List is [recipe[vagrant_main]]
[Mon, 30 Jul 2012 08:55:18 +0200] INFO: Run List expands to [vagrant_main]
[Mon, 30 Jul 2012 08:55:18 +0200] INFO: Starting Chef Run for lucid64
[Mon, 30 Jul 2012 08:55:18 +0200] INFO: Running start handlers
[Mon, 30 Jul 2012 08:55:18 +0200] INFO: Start handlers complete.
[Mon, 30 Jul 2012 08:55:18 +0200] INFO: Processing execute[apt-get update] action run (apt::default line 20)
[default] Destroying VM and associated drives...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/net-ssh-2.2.2/lib/net/ssh/ruby_compat.rb:33:in `select': closed stream (IOError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/net-ssh-2.2.2/lib/net/ssh/ruby_compat.rb:33:in `io_select'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/net-ssh-2.2.2/lib/net/ssh/ruby_compat.rb:32:in `synchronize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/net-ssh-2.2.2/lib/net/ssh/ruby_compat.rb:32:in `io_select'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/net-ssh-2.2.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/packet_stream.rb:73:in `available_for_read?'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/net-ssh-2.2.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/packet_stream.rb:85:in `next_packet'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/net-ssh-2.2.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:171:in `poll_message'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/net-ssh-2.2.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:166:in `loop'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/net-ssh-2.2.2/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:166:in `poll_message'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/net-ssh-2.2.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:451:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/net-ssh-2.2.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:213:in `preprocess'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/net-ssh-2.2.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:197:in `process'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/net-ssh-2.2.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:161:in `loop'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/net-ssh-2.2.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:161:in `loop_forever'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/net-ssh-2.2.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:161:in `loop'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/net-ssh-2.2.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:269:in `wait'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/communication/ssh.rb:213:in `shell_execute'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/communication/ssh.rb:53:in `execute'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/communication/ssh.rb:110:in `connect'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/communication/ssh.rb:52:in `execute'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/communication/ssh.rb:72:in `sudo'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/provisioners/chef_solo.rb:196:in `run_chef_solo'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/provisioners/chef_solo.rb:189:in `times'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/provisioners/chef_solo.rb:189:in `run_chef_solo'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/provisioners/chef_solo.rb:96:in `provision!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/vm/provision.rb:34:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/vm/provision.rb:31:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/vm/provision.rb:31:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:33:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/vm/forward_ports.rb:24:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:33:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/vm/check_port_collisions.rb:42:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:33:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/env/set.rb:16:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:33:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/vm/clear_forwarded_ports.rb:13:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:33:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/vm/clean_machine_folder.rb:17:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:33:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/vm/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:33:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/general/validate.rb:13:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:33:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/general/check_virtualbox.rb:23:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:33:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/vm/match_mac_address.rb:16:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:33:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/vm/default_name.rb:17:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:33:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/vm/check_guest_additions.rb:33:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:33:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/vm/import.rb:31:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:33:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/vm/check_box.rb:28:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:33:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/vm/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:33:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/general/validate.rb:13:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:33:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/general/check_virtualbox.rb:23:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:33:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:92:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:49:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:49:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/vm.rb:192:in `run_action'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/vm.rb:145:in `up'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/command/up.rb:31:in `execute'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/command/base.rb:116:in `with_target_vms'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/command/base.rb:111:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/command/base.rb:111:in `with_target_vms'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/command/up.rb:24:in `execute'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:42:in `execute'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:167:in `cli'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/vagrant-1.0.3/bin/vagrant:43
    from /usr/bin/vagrant:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/vagrant:23
```

Comment: What does your Vagrantfile look like? Sounds like either a network configuration error or some device like udev isn't installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open ticket for this at https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/516

What worked for me was the following:

1. Updated to **VirtualBox 4.1.20** (from 4.1.18 running on Ubuntu 12.04 host)
2. Updated all **gems** (I use rbenv. Notably my **net-ssh** gem was outdated)
3. Created a **new basebox** using instructions at https://github.com/jedi4ever/veewee/blob/master/doc/vagrant.md

I no longer get the "closed stream (IOError)" issue and can do multi VM vagrant deploys without any issues.

Comment: Just got one "closed stream (IOError)" again so obviously it's not fixed. But it is far less common for me.

Answer (score 0):

see: https://github.com/dcarley/vbox_natbug

```
config.vm.define :ubuntu_amd do |c|
  c.vm.box = "lucid64"
  c.vm.customize(["modifyvm", :id, "--nictype1", "Am79C973"])
end
```

Maybe it can help...